# is it possible to retrieve google links from strings?

Tags: java, android, performance

i currently have a menu item that looks like the following

```
case R.id.action_settings_rate_app:
    Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent3.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.raptools.app.raptools"));
    startActivity(intent3);
    bRet=true;
    break;
```

where it says .setData(Uri.parse i would like to call a string and place the link market://details?id=com.raptools.app.raptools in the string.... is this possible to do?

the reason i want to do this is because i have over 25 java files that all call the menu and have the same links in them..... if i could call the string i would only need to change the one string value instead of having to change all the menu items one by one

thanks in advance

Comment: you can just replace the string with a public static final variable.

Comment: Using literal strings in code is not a good idea, actually it's a bad habit. Use a final String variable. Then you just need to mantain one single string when you want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

It's totally possible, for that you need handle the links, [see this link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html).

So, in your `Activity` you can get the parameters.

eg.:

MyActivity1

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("my-scheme://my-domain.com/params1"));
startActivity(intent);
```

MyActivity2

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    Uri data = getIntent().getData();
    String p = data.getLastPathSegment(); // Variable p is params1.      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into using a Java Properties file to store this value (and possibly others) for your application. If you do this, you can just change the values in the .properties file and your code can pick up the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi as per my understanding with your 
You want to place link into string.so that it will be easy for you to change at one place
Let me know if I misunderstand your question

You can add link into String/ String builder
For example
Initialize string variable with link 
Like

```
String urlLink="market://details?id=com.raptools.app.raptools";

case R.id.action_settings_rate_app:
Intent intent3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent3.setData(Uri.parse(urlLink));
startActivity(intent3);
break;
```

You can add string variable into separate class and declared String variable as public static into it
So that using class name you will get the urlLink wherever you want in the application